# Manage Our employee mobiles

Tags: android

In our Organization we have 200 Android O.S mobiles for our customer support people.All employees are tracked using GPS.I had developed the tracking application that will send Location of mobiles for every 1 minute to my server.It is working well,but i want several extra features

1. I want to install my tracking application using another application
   on mobile with out user interaction.
2. I want to restrict the user not to delete the application
3. I want to restrict the user not to change settings(Location ,Date
   time .. e.t.c)

How can i achieve these.Please tell me what the different ways to do this?Without these restrictions my entire project will be failed.We already spent so much on this project.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #1 can not be done. If you want to silently install applications, you need to write you custom installer and sign it with System certificate. For this you need to build custom Android image (or use already pre-built ROM images with open private certificates). But I don't think this is deal breaker. As company may install application before giving out the device to employees.

The #2 can not be done without root. So you can root each device and install the application to `/system/app` folder. Users will not be able to remove the app using standard Package Manager.

The #3 can not be done. You can modify Settings.apk and remove Time/Date features, but you won't be able to install it without signing this package with System certificate. Also, any other component with System privileges may trigger Date/Time/Location update. Your best bet here is to detect when time/date/location is changed beyond normal threshold (like +2 hours, or +200 km in distance).

Comment: Thanks for the Information,Please provide some guide lines to modify Settings.apk and Installer.apk.Is  certificate that is created and signed by me is sufficiant or i have to sign it by trusted authoriy\ty like Versign.I wont publish this application on Android market.I only install them on Phones bought by our Organization.

Comment: You have to use Certificate that is used to create Android OS image. And there is (usually) no way you can get this certificate for stock ROMs. Hence there is no reason to modfiy Settings.apk.

Comment: Do you mean Even God can,t do this? If this is the case i have give up.